# STOP receiving SMSes when using Twilio with C#.net

Tags: c#, twilio

I am sending SMS via [twilio C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install) to selected phone numbers.
I see in FAQs in twilio that it is possible to filter out the numbers who do not wish to receive SMSes. I see this kind of information in the link:
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering

My questions are:

1) When user replies STOP, how does twilio handles it?

2) How will my application know that someone has replied "STOP" and opted out from receiving messages?  (Actually I want to update database when someone replies "STOP" to twilio and unsubscribe)

Comment: +1 for wanting to honour customer's communication preferences!

Answer (score 10):

Twilio Evangelist here.

This is a great question: for normal numbers when the persons sends back a ['STOP' message](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering), Twilio will prevent your account from sending an SMS to that person again. However we will also log the 'STOP' message to your SMS logs  so that you know they have opted out.

The person sending the 'STOP' SMS will then get this message

"You have successfully been unsubscribed You will not receive any more messages from this number. Reply START to resubscribe."

If you attempt to send them an SMS again, you will get an error from the REST API: "21610: Message cannot be sent to the 'To' number because the customer has replied with STOP".

The person can opt back into your messages by sending a 'START' message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You Say that "We will also pass the stop message to your application..". Do I need to specify any web page (.aspx in my case )? Will you pass stopping sms information attached to a page in form of querystring ?

Comment: I mean, if user replies with "STOP", will Twilio  redirect the control to some page of my application ?

Comment: The SMS will be sent to your normal Messaging endpoint, just like any other SMS. But Twilio will not deliver any reply in the TwiML to the end user. Your app will receive 'STOP', and then you can no longer send messages to that person.

Comment: What's meant is that... you have to create a webhook and integrate that with Twilio (INBOUND REQUEST CONFIG) to receive the inbound messages and handle it in your application in apt way.

In case of long code Twilio will handle it on its own. Whereas, in case of short code the entire implementation should be handled in your application.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that twilio 'intercepts' the SMS message, recognizes the 'STOP', does what processing it needs to to suppresses future SMS messages on their end, but the original message will still get passed to you as always, so you will have the ability to still handle it on you end as well.

Comment: Except that you can't preempt the messages they send out and replace it with one of your own.