# Reflect Twilio Opt Outs/Blacklist Requests in My App

Tags: sms, response, twilio, blacklist

Not finding much (any) info on this subject, so thought I would go ahead and post a question.  I would like to reflect blacklist SMS requests/responses in my application instead of just letting Twilio handle it.  Is there a mechanism for accessing my account's Twilio SMS blacklist?  Or a message status on responses?  Or do I just need to parse every single response for keywords?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on if your using a 10 digit number or a shortcode.

Twilio addresses handling stop, help, and other keywords here

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-you-customize-the-helpstop-messages-for-sms-filtering

The stop keyword is what sets up the blacklist as described here

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/why-am-i-seeing-the-message-fromto-pair-violates-a-blacklist-rule

You may also want to read this

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering

I know I read somewhere that you could request twilio not handle them so you could, but that may only have applied to the short codes previously. Basically you need to contact Twilio support

Comment: Good question.  For us, for now, it is a 10 digit number.  I am fine with Twilio's STOP filtering.  We do use it.  I just want to process the requests in my application as well.

Comment: I would contact them. They may be able to give you some sort of notification when this happens. But as far as default functionality it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Finally finding some very similar questions that basically address this challenge.  Sounds like parsing the returning message for "STOP" is really about the only option (to capture the opt out request in real time, that is).

[STOP receiving SMSes when using Twilio with C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548739/stop-recieving-smses-when-using-twilio-with-c-net)

[Twilio SMS gateway - Blacklist / STOP back to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548844/twilio-sms-gateway-blacklist-stop-back-to-database?rq=1)